# Open Source Java Date and Time picker

Tags: java, datetime, jar

Does anyone know of a good single jar date and time selector library, that will output what you've selected as a String?  Something like the Nebula [CDateTime](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php) widget, but not an Eclipse widget.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwingX is great. You will use JXDatePicker.
[SwingX](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t45447.html)

Comment: This doesn't have a time picker though, does it?

Comment: Decided to extend the JXDatePicker class and include a couple of JSpinners for the input of the time.  Thanks.